# How to print html text depending on condition using reactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

simple question here having this :

```js
<Row>
   { "Client : " && elt.client?.libelle}
</Row>
```

I'd like that if elt.client is defined, displaying :

> Client : client libelle

Comment: Just do `{!!elt.client && "Client : client libelle"}`. If the string is dynamic, you can do `{ !!elt.client && "Client : " + elt.client.libelle}`. Adding double ! will parse your first statement to a boolean which is basically an exists check. If you add && and the first argument is true, the part after will be returned and displayed. If the value is false, nothing will be displayed.

Comment: I'm still getting  *client : null*  with  *{!!elt.client && "Client : client libelle"}*  when client isn't defined. But you understood what i want

Comment: Ok never mind im dumb, with !!elt.client.libelle, it works. Thanks a lot man

Comment: No worries, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but maybe this help?

```
<Row>
  {elt.client ? elt.client.libelle : elseStatement}
</Row>
```

Meaning: `if (elt.client) {
return elt.client.libelle
} else {
return "whatever else you want"
}

`

Comment: Or `{ elt.client &&  elt.client.libelle }` or `{ el.client?.libelle || 'something else' }`

Comment: I want to display either nothing if client isn't defined or "client : client libelle" if client is defined

Comment: You can still use the if statement then, can you not?

Comment: I can't because it is in an html return (with react hooks)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of ternary operator (? and : ). This operator is frequently used as an alternative to an if...else statement.

```
<Row>
 { elt?.client?.libelle ? ("Client : " + elt.client.libelle) : "" }
</Row>
```

It takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (?), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is falsy.

Also, you can utilise optional chaining (?.) operator of JavaScript which prevents an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined).

In this case, if `elt` is undefined, it won't throw error. Hence, if all `elt`, `elt.client` and `elt.client.libelle` is defined and the value is no null, "Client : " + elt.client.libelle will display.